# could not find file Hibernate OSGi bundle

Tags: hibernate, osgi

I am developing an application which makes use of the Hibernate framework into OSGi, more concrete, Equinox Server. Thus, I have generated the libraries bundle and the client plug-in where I am programming the communication between the business logic and the database, making use of the libraries bundle mentioned before. In my project I have a the following structure of packages:

```
/src
    /com.cartif.manager
    /com.cartif.hibernatemappings
```

In the manager package I have those classes in charge of communicating the client with the database and mappings one contains the configuration file and hibernate mapping files. Nevertheless, when I am deploying the bundles, the references are working well, but I get an Exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not find file: .\com\cartif\hibernatemappings\hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2136)
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DatabaseCommunicator.createDBSession(DatabaseCommunicator.java:89)
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DWHManager.createDBSession(DWHManager.java:53)
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.osgi.DWH_Handler.<init>(DWH_Handler.java:65)
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.osgi.Activator.run(Activator.java:67)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\com\cartif\hibernatemappings\hibernateTUC.cfg.xml (El sistema no puede hallar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2133)
```

This Exception is thrown in the line where I am reading the cfg.xml:

```
configuration.configure(new File("./com/cartif/hibernatemappingshibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

In the manifest file, I establish the class path of the bundle as:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .
```

I have also tried to get the bundle location, entry paths and so on thrugh the bundle context object, but always the same exception. Do you know how I could access to the configuration file?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already solved!!!! The problem is when the libraries and code are separated, the libraries must be referenced in both bundles which generates a circular dependency. Thus, changing the configuration of the manifest on the client side and, instead of importing packages, it is referred to the whole bundle (Require-Bundle). Then, it is avoided the circular dependency and, furthermore, the server side can import the package where the Hibernate files are placed.

Comment: Jose, be aware that Hibernate was not developed with OSGi in mind. We had so many classloading issues that we gave up and moved to another JPA implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Could I ask you for JPA useful frameworks in OSGi???

Comment: There are two options that I'm aware of: Gemini JPA and Aries JPA.